# Cannot create JMS with netbeans 8.2

Tags: java, netbeans, jms

I am trying to create a jms project using netbeans, i'm following a book tutorial but once i create the JMS Resource in the web application i have different outcome in the project tab and it doesn't work. After i create a jms resource query i should have sun-resources.xml under Server Resources, what it ends up creating is glassfish-resources.xml under Configuration Files. Also from Glassfish Domain Admin Console i should be able to see the newly created jms under *Resources > JMS Resources > Destination Resources* but instead there's .

Imgur screenshot in comments

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/EMMmN book outcome

Comment: imgur.com/a/9gIJH my outcome

Comment: imgur.com/a/ugQBW my glassfish domain admin console